# Relationships in a triangle

Tags: triangles

[image]

Here is the question, I can''t figure out how to explain this algebraically.

Comment: Have you tried it? Can you show us what you have got so far?

Comment: Are those the equations of lines? $5y-3=0$, $4y+x=0$?

Comment: @Tejas I certainly hope those aren't equations of lines, because then two of the lines would be $7=0$ and $14=0$. They are lengths of the line segments for some values $x$ and $y$.